# How do I manage generated source files in a C# project when the project is version controlled in TFS and built with MSBuild?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, xsd

I have an XSD which I am using to generate source code each time I build a project. Currently, the code is being generated using a pre-build event:

```
call "$(VS100COMNTOOLS)vsvars32.bat"
xsd.exe "$(ProjectDir)XSD\Foo.xsd" /classes /outputdir:"$(ProjectDir)GeneratedSource"
```

I then added the resulting $(ProjectDir)\GeneratedSource\Foo.cs file to my project so that it was picked up by Visual Studio. This works well within Visual Studio, I can update the XSD then rebulid and have my new Foo.cs available.

The problem is when I check the generated source file into TFS two things happen:

1. The file is marked as read-only when checked out of TFS, so the pre-build command fails to execute on my local machine until I manually change the file attribute.
2. The pre-build command is failing on my build server, presumably for the same reason.

   $/{Project}/Solution.sln - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s), View Log File
   EXEC: Error generating classes for schema 'C:{Project}\XSD\Foo'.
   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1063): The command "call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"

   xsd.exe "C:{project}\XSD\Foo.xsd" /classes /outputdir:"C:{Project}\GeneratedSource"" exited with code 1.

I would like the XSD to generate the source files each time the project builds. Is there a different approach which I should be taking or do I simply need to figure out how to prevent the files being checked out of TFS from being readonly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated files should not be in source control, it pretty much defeats the purpose. Or in your case: makes it impossible. Just put the generator in source control and add the generated files to your project using a wildcard like

```
 <Compile Include="$(ProjectDir)GeneratedSource\*.cs"/>
```

IIIRC it's possibly this doesn't play nicely with Visual Studio in that it expands the wildcard and alters your project. To get around this, put the above into a seperate msbuild file, and import that file into your project right before the line containing `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`

Comment: I agree with the notion of keeping generated source out of source control. This solution works in Visual Studio, but my build server (TFS / MSBuild) is not picking up the generated class.

Answer (score 0):

```
call "$(VS100COMNTOOLS)vsvars32.bat"
xsd.exe "$(ProjectDir)XSD\Foo.xsd" /classes /outputdir:"$(ProjectDir)GeneratedSource"
```

Add a Delete or attrib call to your prebuild command, to delete the source controlled file or remove the read only flags.